# Iterate over the current linked list without referring to it explicitly

Tags: java, linked-list

i have a linked list and i need to write a method to take an input as a string and check all the elements in the linked list for a match, the method has to return the number of matches.

The problem is that i need to refer to the current linked list without taking it as an input into the method.

```
public int count(E elem) 
{
    int count;
    for (E list : x)
    {
        if(this.removeAtHead().equals(elem))
        {
            count++;
        }
        else{}
    }
    return count;
}
```

i need to replace x with the current linked list.

An example of using the method is:

```
public static void main(String[ ] args) 
{
    LinkedList<String> first = new LinkedList<String>();

    first.insertAtTail("abc");
    first.insertAtTail("def");
    first.insertAtTail("def");
    first.insertAtTail("xyz");

    System.out.println( first.count("def") ); // prints "2"

    first.insertAtTail(null);
    first.insertAtTail("def");
    first.insertAtTail(null);

    System.out.println( first.count("def") ); // prints "3"
    System.out.println( first.count(null) ); // prints "2"
}
```

Comment: Are you using the built-in `java.util.LinkedList`, or something else?

Comment: Why can't you refer to it/pass it as argument?

Answer (score 1):

Just make it `for (E list : this)`, as follows:

```
public int count(E elem) 
{
    int count;
    for (E list : this)
    {
        if (removeAtHead().equals(elem))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: The `else{}` is unnecessary. `else` is optional in Java.

Comment: @SteveKuo I know, just wasn't sure whether the function might've been partial (but I suppose it wasn't).

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a private variable within your class that contains a List/or list of lists(should you need to keep track of multiple lists). You could then reference the list within other functions of this class or use getters and setters.

Comment: This seems better suited to be a comment, whereas you ask him a question and didn't provide a clear answer.